# Empty custom prototype cell

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, storyboard

I'm new in iPhone development and have problem with prototype cell. 
In my storyboard, I have navigation controller. I pushed it with view controller (as main window), it has a button, when I click it I open tableView controller with custom prototype cell

```
- (IBAction)searchClick:(id)sender {
CNCarTableController *car = [[CNCarTableController alloc]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:car animated:TRUE];
```

}

But when it opens it has empty rows

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:     ( NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TransportCell";
  CNTransportCell *cell = [tableView       dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

// Configure the cell...
if(cell == nil){
   cell = [[CNTransportCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
//cell.textLabel.text = @"bmv";

cell.name = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:100];
[cell.name setText:@"a text"];
cell.number.text = @"number";
cell.car.text = @"car";
return cell;
```

}

But if will use `cell.textLabel.text = @"bmv";` all works ok. But for custom cell way with tags or cell.lbl.text don't work. What is wrong there? Can it be a nuance of navigation controller with view controller?

Custom cell code:

```
  @interface CNTransportCell : UITableViewCell

  @property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UILabel *name;
  @property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UILabel *number;
  @property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UILabel *car;
```

@end

```
   @implementation CNTransportCell
   @synthesize name;
   @synthesize number;
   @synthesize car;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
  {
   self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
  if (self) {
    // Initialization code
  }
   return self;
 }
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
 {
   [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

// Configure the view for the selected state
  }

@end
```

Comment: how you are making your custom cell?

Comment: @amar I pasted the code of custum cell, Indentifier is TransportCell

Answer (score 0):

you have done small mistake there. Your custom cell class is "CNPlayerCell" & you are allocating new cells from "CNTransportCell" class.

One more thing, have you assigned custom class to your prototype cell in IB? (In identity inspector)

Comment: yes :) sorry I copied other class but CNTransportCell is same, problem in other place.

Comment: Have you assigned custom class to your prototype Cell in Identity inspector? next thing, check for "case sensitive" cell identifier. Is it same? Let me know. can you please update your code with correct class?

Comment: yes I did these things, yeah they are same. I've updated it yet, also I try to use this arcticle for create custum cell programmaticly it is work http://www.danielhanly.com/blog/tutorial/custom-uitableviewcell-not-quite-as-daunting-as-id-thought, but when i use prototype cell it is not working.